# TypeScript React: How to pass a type argument to MUI DataGrid custom Toolbar?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I'm using a custom Toolbar with Material UI DataGrid, and passing a bunch of props to it with this object syntax:

```
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import InternalToolbar from "../InternalToolbar";

<DataGrid
  {/* ...other props */}
  components={{
    Toolbar: InternalToolbar,
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    toolbar: {
      itemName,
      fields,
      setAnchorEl,
      onAddSubmit,
      onAddOpen: onModalOpen,
      addLoading: modalLoading,
    },
  }}
/>
```

In the `Internal Toolbar` component, I need it to take a `FieldTypes` type argument like so:

```
type Props<FieldTypes> = {
  itemName: string;
  fields: DataFields<FieldTypes>;
  setAnchorEl: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<HTMLButtonElement | null>>;
  onAddSubmit: OnSubmitFormModal<FieldTypes>;
  onAddOpen?: () => void;
  addLoading?: boolean;
};

const InternalToolbar = <FieldTypes,>({
  itemName,
  fields,
  setAnchorEl,
  onAddSubmit,
  onAddOpen,
  addLoading = false,
}: Props<FieldTypes>) => (
  <GridToolbarContainer>
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AddModal
        itemName={itemName}
        fields={fields}
        onSubmit={onAddSubmit}
        onOpen={onAddOpen}
        loading={addLoading}
      />
    </Box>
    <Box>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton ref={setAnchorEl} />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton ref={setAnchorEl} />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport
        csvOptions={{ fileName: `${itemName}Data` }}
        printOptions={{
          hideFooter: true,
          hideToolbar: true,
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  </GridToolbarContainer>
);
```

How can I pass a type argument to the InternalToolbar component? I've tried passing InternalToolbar into DataGrid like this:

```
components={{
  Toolbar: (props) => InternalToolbar<FieldTypes>(props),
}}
```

but that creates an infinite render loop. Is there any way in TypeScript to pass a type argument to a function without calling it? Or do something akin to

```
components={{
  Toolbar: InternalToolbar as (typeof InternalToolbar)<FieldTypes>,
}}
```

I'm stuck here, so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any luck in solving? Have same issue.

Comment: @Madrus Unfortunately no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid
  {/* ...other props */}
  components={{
    Toolbar: () => (
      <InternalToolbar 
        itemName={itemName}
        fields={fields}
        setAnchorEl={setAnchorEl}
        onAddSubmit={onAddSubmit}
        onAddOpen={onModalOpen}
        addLoading={modalLoading}
      />
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).